# How can I rewrite a path to a querystring in a wordpress permalink URL?

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, permalinks

I need to rewrite some wordpress permalinks so that `site.ca/anypage/page/anytab` rewrites to `site.ca/anypage/?pagetab=anytab`. I've tried a bunch of rewrites that I think should be working but wordpress is just giving me a 404 on the full typed in URL (rather than the proper querystring'd page).

Here's what I've got so far (using a specific page for testing instead of anypage/page/anytab:

```
RewriteRule ^community-alumni/conference-services/page/(.*)$ community-alumni/conference-services/?pagetab=$1 [L]
```

This rewrite is just giving me a 404 error however, I know the Regex, at least is passing because if I change the Rewrite to a `R=301,L` redirect then the page does redirect to the querystring'd page and pulls up the appropriate content, ie:

```
RewriteRule ^community-alumni/conference-services/page/(.*)$ community-alumni/conference-services/?pagetab=$1 [R=301,L]
```

Redirects to `community-alumni/conference-services/?pagetab=summer-hotel` and pulls in the page content. So I can't see why the rewrite which should be pulling in the same content as the querystring'd URL is pulling a 404 - I have a feeling it has to do with wordpress? In the wordpress `.htaccess` I have this rewrite after `RewriteBase` and before `RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]`

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a feeling it has to do with wordpress?

It probably is, and I'm sure there's some internal to wordpress way of handling it using their rewrite API and (probably) the post_rewrite_rules hook. (More info at the [wordpress stack exchange](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/7243/custom-rewrite-rules-for-pages).

But if that doesn't work, you can always try the `P` flag to internally proxy the request so that the `REQUEST_URI` that wordpress' controller sees is the one without all the stuff after the `/page/` (which is most likely what is causing wordpress to puke).

```
RewriteRule ^community-alumni/conference-services/page/(.*)$ /community-alumni/conference-services/?pagetab=$1 [L,P]
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. I was going to use the WP Rewrite but I have to rewrite that to the WP page such as `index.php?pagename=page-slug` where I won't be able to easily get the slug from the path captured in the regex... Your suggestion is working with the exception that I had to add the server to the rewrite otherwise it brought back `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/...` instead of 'http : //localhost:8888/...` - that is fine though, I can just change this on the live .htaccess. Update your answer, plz, so I can accept it.

Comment: I also modified it to answer the original question of `anypage/page/anytab` - here is the final rewrite: `RewriteRule ^(.*)/page/(.*)$ http ://localhost:8888/site/$1/?pagetab=$2&pagepath=$1 [P,L]`

Comment: @tsdexter that's my bad. You just need to add a `/` to the front to make the URI absolute

Comment: had to add `/site/` actually for it to work - the live site exists in the root, not `/site/` - is there a way I can use the RewriteBase in it, instead of adding `/site/` as the RewriteBase is set to `/site/` on local and `/` on live.

Comment: @tsdexter Yeah, you can use `RewriteBase /site/` and change it to `RewriteBase /` on the live site, but then you'd need to remove the `/` in front of the rewrite rule's target (like the way before I edited the answer).

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. Using `RewriteRule ^(.*)/page/(.*)/?$ /$1/?pagetab=$2&pagepath=$1 [P,L]` gives me the server error: `The requested URL /community-alumni/conference-services/ was not found on this server.` even with RewriteBase set to `/site/` adding `/site/` to the RewriteRule makes it work. It's not a huge issue, I can modify it for live.